# Getting error in running ExportReport Python code in ArcMap

Tags: python, report, arcgis, arcmap

i am unable to generate pdf report using ExportReport function of Arcgis 10.2. getting error of   **IOError: Could not open report template**

tried different template files but still getting this error.
Template directory is correct. checked all the directory positions.

**Code**

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\Abrar ahmad\Documents\ArcGIS\New_Rwp_Cencus(12-17-2014).mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "",df):
if lyr.name == "New_Districts_5_without_limit":
    arcpy.mapping.ExportReport(lyr,r"C:\Users\Abrar ahmad\Documents\ArcGIS\test.rlf",r"C:\Users\Abrar ahmad\Documents\ArcGIS\ProjectReport2.pdf","USE_RLF")
del mxd
```

**Complete Error Data:**

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 7, in 
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 181, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 515, in ExportReport
    return report_source._arc_object.ExportReport(*gp_fixargs((report_layout_file, output_file, dataset_option, report_title, starting_page_number, page_range, report_definition_query, extent, field_map), True))
IOError: Could not open report template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute your code inside try/except/finally and see if this gives some hint:

```
import arcpy  
import sys  
import traceback  
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\Abrar ahmad\Documents\ArcGIS\New_Rwp_Cencus(12-17-2014).mxd")  
try:  

  df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]  
  for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "",df):  
  if lyr.name == "New_Districts_5_without_limit":  
   arcpy.mapping.ExportReport(lyr,r"C:\Users\Abrar ahmad\Documents\ArcGIS\test.rlf",r"C:\Users\Abrar ahmad\Documents\ArcGIS\ProjectReport2.pdf","USE_RLF")  

except arcpy.ExecuteError:   
    # Get the tool error messages   
    msgs = arcpy.GetMessages(2)   


    # Return tool error messages for use with a script tool   
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)   


    # Print tool error messages for use in Python/PythonWin   
    print msgs  


except:  
    # Get the traceback object  
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]  
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]  


    # Concatenate information together concerning the error into a message string  
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n" + str(sys.exc_info()[1])  
    msgs = "ArcPy ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"  


    # Return python error messages for use in script tool or Python Window  
    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)  
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)  


    # Print Python error messages for use in Python / Python Window  
    print pymsg + "\n"  
    print msgs  
finally:  
    del mxd
```